# pyVisa with cx_Freeze - TypeError: unexpected keyword argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, cx-freeze, visa

I've got a script using pyvisa. Over python console everything works fine but frozen I get a TypeError.

debug.py:

```
import visa

def main():
    visa.log_to_screen()
    rm = visa.ResourceManager()
    # works
    instr = rm.open_resource("GPIB0::12::INSTR")
    # fails in frozen executable
    instr = rm.open_resource("GPIB0::12::INSTR", write_termination="\r\n")
if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

setup.py:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import os, site

[python_dir, site_dir] = site.getsitepackages()
include_files = []
missing_dll = ["msvcr100.dll"]
for dll in missing_dll:
    include_files.append((os.path.join(python_dir, dll), dll))

buildOptions_exe = dict(
    compressed = False,
    # includes = ["pyvisa"],       # doesn't solve this issue
    include_files = include_files
    )

setup(
    name = "Debugger",
    author = "Name",
    version = "0.0.0",
    options = dict(build_exe = buildOptions_exe),
    executables = [Executable("debug.py"),]
```

Execution of frozen script:

```
O:\>build\exe.win32-3.3\debug.exe
2015-02-06 09:51:38,270 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Created library wrapper for C:\Windows\system32\visa32.dll
2015-02-06 09:51:38,290 - pyvisa - DEBUG - viOpenDefaultRM(<cparam 'P' (02BCDA58)>,) -> 0
2015-02-06 09:51:38,290 - pyvisa - DEBUG - Created ResourceManager with session8240592
2015-02-06 09:51:38,360 - pyvisa - DEBUG - viOpen(8240592, 'GPIB0::12::INSTR', 0, 0, <cparam 'P' (02BCDA58)>) -> 1073676413
O:\build\exe.win32-3.3\library.zip\pyvisa\ctwrapper\functions.py:1059: VisaIOWarning: VI_SUCCESS_DEV_NPRESENT (1073676413): Session opened successfully, but the device at the specified address is not responding.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python\WinPython-32bit-3.3.2.3\python-3.3.2\lib\site-packages\cx_Freeze\initscripts\Console3.py", line 27, in <module>
  File "debug.py", line 14, in <module>
    main()
  File "debug.py", line 12, in main
    instr = rm.open_resource("GPIB0::12::INSTR", write_termination="\r\n")
TypeError: open_resource() got an unexpected keyword argument 'write_termination'
```

Where can this redefinition come from?

Comment: is there really an `write_termination` argument exists in opensource method?

Comment: Yes. After opening `instr` it is forwarded by [`open_resource()`](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/resourcemanager.html#pyvisa.highlevel.ResourceManager.open_resource) to [`instr.write_termination`](http://pyvisa.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/resources.html#pyvisa.resources.SerialInstrument.write_termination).